# Why is Viewer' getViewerToken getting called infinite times?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

The function `getViewerToken` is called infinitely since today without any code change. Is this bug on our side or a bug in the forge viewer?

```js
        iframe.viewer = new iframe.Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(iframe.viewerDiv, { extensions: extensions });
        let options = {
            // 'env': 'AutodeskProduction',
            'env': 'MD20ProdEU', //svf2
            'api': 'D3S', //svf2
            'getAccessToken': function(onTokenReady) {
                     ...
            };
  .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewer calls the `getAccessToken` function whenever the token needs to be refreshed. When you're calling the callback function inside `getAccessToken`, make sure that the second parameter (expiration time of the new token in seconds) is a positive integer number. Perhaps your code is passing in zero or a negative number, forcing the viewer to repeatedly ask for new tokens.